# How do I get the index of all elements in a list, according to data given in a data.frame in R?

Tags: r

I have a data frame and a list which is as such:

```
> df
               value
1                5
2               25
3                6
4               70
```

And list:

```
> y

[[1]]
[1]  5 6 70 25

[[2]]
[1]  6 70 5 25
```

How do I make the list return the index of each elements such that it is:

```
> y

[[1]]
[1]  1 3 4 2

[[2]]
[1]  3 4 1 2
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `match` to get the index by looping over the `list` and matching with the 'value' column of 'df'

```
lapply(y, function(x) match(x, df$value))
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 3 4 2

#[[2]]
#[1] 3 4 1 2
```

---

Or without anonymous function

```
lapply(y, match, df$value)
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(value = c(5, 25, 6, 70))
y <- list(c(5, 6, 70, 25), c(6, 70, 5, 25))
```

Comment: @WeiShung it would still work as long as we arre matching with a single column 'df$value'

Comment: @WeiShung for large data, `vapply` would be faster `vapply(y, function(x) FUN = match(x, df$value), FUN.VALUE = integer(length(y[[1]])))`

Comment: Thank you. I discover a problem. How would you do this if the "6" in the Value column is now a 5 and one of the list contain 2 "5". I want them to show index "1", "3" rather than just "1".

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the data in the Note at the end:

```
Map(match, y, df)
```

giving:

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 3 4 2

[[2]]
[1] 3 4 1 2
```

Not needed with the data here, but if your `df` actually has more than one column specify that the `value` column is the one to use like this:

```
Map(match, y, df["value"])
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "               value
1                5
2               25
3                6
4               70"
df <- read.table(text = Lines)

y <- list(c(5, 6, 70, 25), c(6, 70, 5, 25))
```